# Christoffel Symbols: when did the bracket notation first appear?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, math-history

An early notation to Christoffel symbols is:

\begin{equation}
\begin{Bmatrix}
  m  \\
  \hspace{1.5mm}b\hspace{5mm} c\hspace{1.5mm} 
\end{Bmatrix} = \frac{1}{2}g^{ma}\{ \partial_{b}g_{ca} + \partial_{c}g_{ab} - \partial_{a}g_{bc}\} \tag{1}
\end{equation}

with these curly brackets.

Now, in Einstein's notebook and in the seminal paper of Einstein Field Equations we see a clear usage of this notation:

[image]

and

[image]

I'm not sure if was Einstein indeed the first one to use this curly notation (or the german publishers). **So, It was Elwin Christoffel the one who introduced this notation? If no,  would like to know the one who first have used this notation.**

Comment: Where did you acquire that image from Einstein's notebook?

Comment: From Google:  https://www.google.com/search?q=einstein%27s+notebook&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjM-JnbqvntAhUONLkGHRUUBpsQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=Einstein&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQARgAMgQIIxAnMgQIIxAnMgUIABCxAzIFCAAQsQMyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6BAgAEEM6CAgAELEDEIMBOgcIIxDqAhAnOgcIABCxAxBDUNH38gJY5YPzAmCIkfMCaAJwAHgAgAGUAYgB8QaSAQMxLjeYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ7ABCsABAQ&sclient=img&ei=YlnuX8y_G47o5OUPlaiY2Ak&bih=667&biw=1366

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bracket notation and brace notation was the *first* notation, due to Christoffel and appearing in his 1869 [paper](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0070?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B50%5D,%22view%22:%22info%22%7D). See both the 3rd and 4th pages.

The $\Gamma$-notation is due to Einstein in his work on general relativity.

This is discussed, with links to a bunch of papers by different authors (Christoffel, Einstein, Ricci, Weyl, *et al.*), in the question I asked about this issue a couple of years ago [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7974/notation-for-christoffel-symbols).  It is suggested in comments there that the use of $\Gamma$ by Einstein might be an allusion to "gravitation" and the $\Gamma$-notation should be called Einstein symbols instead of Christoffel symbols.

Answer (score 0):

In [Christoffel's original paper](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0070?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B52%5D,%22view%22:%22fulltext%22%7D) (according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols#cite_note-christoffel-7)) introducing Christoffel symbols, he uses this notation (although with square brackets).